# Choosing API Gateway tool to implement SOA/microservices architecture

Tags: web-services, rest, api, soa, microservices

I am certain I need to use an API Gateway, but I can't understand the main differences between the different tools in my use case scenario.

Currently, I have multiple services (DBs, Mobile App, Web App and some additional systems. Consider there are 15 different services) that communicate with each other through REST APIs. This is difficult to manage and test, so I would like to change the architecture into something more like what Netflix is doing with Zuul.

Ideally, the services don't know about the other services. They send a request to a specific endpoint (the API Gateway). Then, the API Gateway interacts with the necessary services and sends the response back.
Here is one example in practice: a service sends a request to a custom (endpoint) connector, the request is parsed, broken down into smaller requests that are sent to other services (that own the specific content requested), get the content back in the response, gather all the responses, create a final response with all the content gathered, send the response back to the first service that sent a request.

I need high availability, scalibility, fault tolerance, the ability to monitor and test all services in one place, ability to do canary testing, easy to add new services and manage the older services. I value open source software and mature software. Should run off premise.

The best solutions that I believe would solve my problem are: WSO2, Apigee, Zuul and Amazon API Gateway. I don't know which is more appropriate for my use case. I have looked at others, but I haven't found any advantages in features or cost against these 4.

Thank you for your feedback regarding advantages and disadvantages regarding these technologies! Other suggestions are also welcome!

Notes:
Not all of my services are on AWS, but some are.
The system needs to handle peaks with tens of thousands of requests per minute that happen regurarly, but never continuasly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider the Forum Sentry API Security Gateway from Forum Systems (I work for Forum Systems).

Based on your example use case, if each of the "smaller request" services are using the same protocols (e.g. HTTPS), message formats (e.g. JSON) and security characteristics (TLS, authentication, etc.) then the solution should be relatively straight forward.

If each service is using different identity or message formats, say, then your API Gateway solution will also need to have strong capabilities around identity and message conversion. For example, one small request may require a BasicAuth header to authenticate to the service, whereas another small request may require a SAML assertion.

Answer (score 0):

As you have landscape of different microservices, wherein each microservice has its own business context and is accessible by REST endponit. In this case, your client need not to aware about each microservice and thus API gateway comes into picture, using which you can have one entry point to all microservices landscape.

There are different API gateway solutions available like you said apigee, apiman etc. These framework gives some basic implementation of features required in API gateways like request throttling, monitization of request calls, authentication handle, centralized security etc.

Netflix's Zuul provides the filters which you need to implement yourself. So, if you are using Zuul, you have to implement all the features which you want to put in your API gateway by yourself.

I hope this explanation helps!!!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!! So if I understood correctly, Zuul may not be the best option if I am looking for a complete solution that works out of the box...

Comment: If you want solution where all the features comes out-of-the-box then use some framework, if you want to implement your custom solutions using filters then use Zuul.